# Which CAD / geometry library should I use: CGAL Open CASCADE or Boost::Geometry something else?

Tags: geometry, cad, cgal, boost-geometry, opencascade

For a customizable laser-cut drawers project I would like to be able to create the connection between any two intersecting perpendicular "2D" objects (with width) programmatically.  For this I need to:

- load and save 2D objects in some standard format.
- extrude 2D object, and make the standard manipulations on 2D objects (specifically subtraction of objects.)
- intersect 2 object, and be able to determine the "line" of intersection.

Which library/tool you would suggest for that?  Can you estimate how difficult it would be to master it to do the above tasks?

Thanks,

Ronen

Answer (score 3):

I'm biased ( PythonOCC dev ), but I'd say OpenCasCade would best fit your needs. Its comes wit Step and Iges importers out of the box ( more formats are supported commercially ), where you'd have to parse and reconstruct the geometry from a file with Boost and CGAL. Finally, neither of those packages deal with nurbs / CAD geometry ( BRep, boundary representation ) but merely triangles ( polygon soup ). So, OCC fits the scope best IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I have experience with OPENCASCADE and CGAL . Boost Geometry is very limited / simple and does not provider support for topological structures , solids , brep etc. The purpose has been quite different from the rest. Certainly, its quality is higher than any of the other two.

Opencascade among the three is least preferable choice in terms of quality. For example, everything is defined in global namespace, there are multiple macro definitions on header files, and has bloated classes. It has quite some support for various algorithms and constructs but only up to some point; for the rest you have to pay. These are somehow understandable, since it has been developed as an in-house library not for public access, and therefore they did not care about such things. The community is quite small, therefore you will have to go searching through the documentation a lot and experiment on how to do things. Usually, there are more than one way to work, and it is common to write many adaptors in your code to interface between different algorithms.

On the other hand CGAL is quite the opposite, has support for almost anything you can imagine, it is quite modern, and there is dedicated community along with very good documentation and examples for most use cases. There are different classes and algorithms depending on trade-off of the problem at hand. There is support for different UI (WIN/QT) and it interfaces well with STL / BOOST containers structures. Comparing to opencascade that does not even have a proper STL compatible iterator class, that is a significant difference.

Therefore, I would strongly suggest to work with CGAL.

In case you are forced to work with OPENCASCADE and want to use CGAL at the same time you will probably have to include header files such that Handle macro is undefed e.g.

```
#include <TopoDS_Shape.h>
#undef Handle
#include <CGAL/Alpha_shape_3.h>
#define  Handle(ClassName)      Handle_##ClassName
```